# Working with Javascript and cross-domain iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, fancybox

I have an iframe that loads a form from another site into my site (I control both domains but they are different).

The iframe is loaded into a fancybox on my site and I would like it to popup an AJAX loading graphic when the form in the iframe is processing.

I know I can't directly add event listeners to the iframe form other site but is there any way that my site can know what is going on in the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's no way of knowing what another iframe is doing.

Have the domain (the one inside the iframe) load the AJAX loading graphic before the content shows up, all on the server side... you don't need the client for this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Luca, but then your form will have to be loaded before the AJAX loading graphic can be displayed. If it is a very large form, this might take a while and will perhaps defeat the purpose of the loading graphic.

Have you considered loading the contents of the form via javascript instead, bypassing the iframe altogether? Just GET the contents of the form and load it into a div? (Granted, if the form you're loading is complex, that might cause more problems)

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely forbidden by browsers to know what is going on in the iframe.